# twitter4j oauth_token comes wrong, although what's listed on app-page works perfect

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Let me explain my question :

In the image we can see a twitter access_token & secret (present on twitter app details page)

[image]

when I use the above two and try to update the status it works.

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Tweet.consumer_key, Tweet.consumer_secret);
        twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(u.getTwittertoken(), u.getTwittersecret()));
        twitter.updateStatus("test");
```

But the oauth_token & oauth_secret that I get through using twitter4j callbackURL

[image]

don't work with the above code. I always get Invalid/Expired Token error.

I don't know what can be the error. Because it used to work once, but stopped suddenly (don't know exactly when)

Please help! It'll be great if someone can share their code for both - getting & saving the token into database & then getting it again from the db to update the status.

Comment: I am having same error, have you found any solution?

Comment: yeah, I found solution. I was getting the token & secret from response, although the right method was to get them from access-token, which was to be retrieved using token present in response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who face the same error, here's what I was doing wrong :

I was trying the token & secret received in twitter-response. Although the correct method is to retrieve them from `accessToken` which has to be retrieved using `oauth_verifier` being sent in twitter-response.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true).setOAuthConsumerKey(Tweet.consumer_key);
            cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Tweet.consumer_secret);
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

            RequestToken requestToken = (RequestToken) mapSession.get("rtoken");

            AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);

            System.out.println("Request Token : " + ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(requestToken, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE));
            System.out.println("Access Token : " + ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(accessToken, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE));


            System.out.println(accessToken.getToken());        //use this further
            System.out.println(accessToken.getTokenSecret());  //use this further
```

Comment: Can you help me with this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926278/whoa-there-the-request-token-for-this-page-is-invalid-how-to-refresh-the-the I have tried but don't understand how to get the refreshed token